# Не отображается картинка в ToolbarItem (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Вместо Name = "Корзина"
Необходимо вставить картинку из пути imageResourceExtension.Images.cart.png

Отображаться она не хочет
Закомментил строки с моими попытками сделать картинку

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MenuDetail"
         Title="x"
         xmlns:local="x"
         xmlns:img="x">

<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Name="Корзина" Priority="0" Clicked="CartClicked" >
        <!--<ToolbarItem.Icon>
            <FileImageSource File="{img:ImageResourceExtension.Images.cart.png}" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>-->
    </ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem  Order="Primary" Name="☺" Priority="1" Clicked="UserClicked">
        <!--<ToolbarItem.Icon>
                <FileImageSource File="{img:ImageResourceExtension.Images.user.png}" />
        </ToolbarItem.Icon>-->
    </ToolbarItem>
</TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
<TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPage BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=listDishTypeModel}"
                     Title="{Binding Path=Name}"
                     BackgroundColor="#1D1D20">
        </ContentPage>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabbedPage.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Напишите конвертер

Comment: @Андрей для .xaml? для чего?

Comment: Я не специалист в `Xamarin`, но в `WPF`/`UWP` для таких целей делают конвертеры

Comment: хм, `File` имеет тип `string`, т.е. вам нужно указать путь к изображению получается. Может расширение разметки не нужно использовать, а просто указать путь? Пробовали так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Мало положить картинку в общую папку.**

Это работает с логотипом, но не с Toolbar.

*Для Toolbar у каждого проекта должны быть картинки :*

```
У iOS - в Resource
У Андроид - в Drawable
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете TabbedPage. Если это не iOS то у вас ничего не получиться.
Посмотрите примеры тут
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/

Если iOS, убедитесь, что файл лежит в проекте iOS в папке Resources/